# Logcat don`t log system apps in latest android 4.3

Tags: android, logcat

In android 4.1.2 I'm using logcat to log system apps (example Update Firmware)

After update to 4.3 logcat stopped writing any logs of system applications

But in the applications themselves as before there Log(tag, '...');

I do not create an application that reads the logs. I use logcat via USB (usb debug is ON)

Question: How to get a log of system applications for android 4.3?